# switch vs object lookup performance (since jsperf is down)

Tags: javascript, performance

The way I see it, for certain situations, there are two ways to do something if some value equals something: a switch or an object lookup.

Using a switch:

```js
var value = ["Hello", "hi", "bYe", "die"][Math.floor(Math.random() * (4))];

switch (value.toLowerCase()) {
  case "hello":
    alert(value + "\n\n" + "hi");
    break;
  case "hi":
    alert(value + "\n\n" + "hello");
    break;
  case "bye":
    alert(value + "\n\n" + "no");
    break;
  case "die":
    alert(value + "\n\n" + "you shot me");
    break;
}
```

Using an object lookup:

```js
var value = ["Hello", "hi", "bYe", "die"][Math.floor(Math.random() * (4))];

var LOOKUP = {
  "hello": function(v) {
    alert(v + "\n\n" + "hi");
  },
  "hi": function(v) {
    alert(v + "\n\n" + "hello");
  },
  "bye": function(v) {
    alert(v + "\n\n" + "no");
  },
  "die": function(v) {
    alert(v + "\n\n" + "you shot me");
  },
};

LOOKUP[value.toLowerCase()](value);
```

I am wondering which would have better performance?

And would there be any unobvious issues/gotchas with either approach?

Comment: There are other ways than jsperf to profile code: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/ or write a simple Node script.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** A Lookup Table is much, much faster.

**UPDATED ANSWER 2020:** The two methods perform pretty much the same in modern browsers, with the switch statement being 20-30% faster than the lookup table.

I had the same question a while back. If jsperf ever gets revived, this is the link.
https://jsperf.com/if-switch-lookup-table/10

Edit: Working benchmark https://jsben.ch/JYZLQ

Comment: Aren't your titles wrong way? Switch looks like lookup and vice versa?

Comment: Indeed, this seems like a wrong answer, lookup is slower

Comment: `switch` indeed is faster on at least latest Chrome and Safari on OSX and I would imagine same applies to all even somewhat modern browsers.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps performance on Switches has improved in the past 9 months. The jsperf link still says lookup tables are faster, but jsbench says the opposite...

Comment: Well, this test is _recreating_ the object every time. It's obviously slower. In a real world scenario, you would define a constant object once and then reiterate only on the lookups. 

I created another test which also includes `Map` http://jsben.ch/HoDxa

**TL;DR** Objects are actually faster on Firefox, but the result stays unchanged on Chrome

Comment: Here's another test: https://jsben.ch/FLez6. Used @Phugo's as a base. Got rid of a bunch of things that were distorting the comparison (function calls mostly). Also threw in a "switch inside function" test, in case there's some compiler automagic optimization I'm not aware of. The four methods seems to do more or less equally, although the switch versions seem slightly faster. I think it boils down to what looks best in your code.

Comment: Agree with @GuillermoAres , the original test above is not much correct

Comment: I've updated the answer, because, as many commenters have pointed out, the claim that the lookup is much-much faster is not true anymore. Also updated the jsbench script link because the original one was pretty much testing irrelevant stuff such as object initialisation and .toLowerCase() (although it still was faster with a switch)

Comment: @GuillermoAres' test is also broken, where the original switchFunc  (https://jsben.ch/FLez6) does not accept a value param, so it just errors out, rapidly ;)

Fixed benchmark is: https://jsben.ch/wdD6x

Comment: Update from 2022: I run [this test](https://jsben.ch/ceeDN). In FF `LOOKUP` is faster about `20%` than `switch` but in Chrome `switch` is faster than about `30%` than `LOOKUP`

Comment: Switch scales worse with more keys, but it's hard to test. You also probably want longer strings to prevent some short string optimizations from making the test different. You also need an unpredictable test pattern, otherwise branch prediction is going to give a big advantage to switch. Here is an attempt: https://jsben.ch/bBtoJ

Comment: @akaltar why when  the strings changed from long strings to short strings the matrix changes to ? 
and what case should I rely on to make a decision?

Comment: @MohammedSaberMohammed You need to look at what kind of keys do you typically have and how many of them, then run a test with that use-case. But in general it's not worth worrying about as the differences are incredibly small

Answer (score 2):

Its a trade-off between time complexity and space complexity,
imagine a switch with 10000 cases, so you would create an object with 10000 keys, and the entire object would have to be loaded in a memory/cache for lookup where as for switch-case it will be jumping from one instruction to another based upon the condition,

I personally prefer object-key lookup over switch-case as its more maintainable code and its extensible design pattern as well.

Comment: I agree, but this doesn't seem to be the consensus I've found. But perhaps most people don't need to worry about maintaining code as much as just getting it working (or have no problem spending more time to write longer, somewhat redundant code for sometimes a little more performance, depending on the language and method).